# Facebook SDK / Parse SDK on Android Studio "cannot resolve symbol R"

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to configure my app with Facebook and Parse. I followed all their instructions and copied/edited the sample code accordingly.

Finally, I was met with this error: 
the import tags
ex.

```
import com.facebook.FacebookRequestError;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
```

etc.

were underlined red, and there were plenty of errors in the project. i clicked the little red bulb above these tags and added the facebook dependency. this got rid of most of the errors and imported the above. however, a new issue was introduced: everything in the project that has: "R.whatever" has the R underlined.

How do I fix this?

Also, if this helps, the userdetails.xml has a rendering issue saying the following:

endering Problems NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.  The following classes could not be found:

```
- com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
```

EDIT

I am using Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse? The missing R errors usually are a resault of a compilation error. Try to first run the clean command on the project and compile it again, and if that doesn't help look for any errors apart from the missing R - you should be able to find one that's different and it's probably causing the problem.